# Autohotkey dealing with Sticky Notes (the Windows UWP App)

Tags: uwp, autohotkey

I've been using other StickyNote tools in Windows and enjoy the accompany of Autohotkey to:

1. WIN+N to create a new one
2. WIN+SHIFT+N to show me all my notes
   Until most recently, i notice that our company IT installed the UWP from Windows "Windows Stikcy Notes", and finding it able to sync with my account. This is a killer feature to me.
   https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4QGHW
   But then I got touble to really call the app to do anything.

What I have achieved:
to start it with a shortcut .lnk -- no problem

```
fStickyNotesLnk = Sticky Notes.lnk
    If !FileExist(fStickyNotesLnk) {
        return
    }
```

to identify the main window -- no good way because it's always the ApplicationFrameHost.exe behind, so that I turn to image matching
[the image I used for matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W9D8.jpg)

```
    WinGet, id, List, ahk_exe ApplicationFrameHost.exe

    CoordMode, Pixel, Window
    Loop, %id%
    {
        hWnd := id%A_Index%
        WinActivate, ahk_id %hWnd% 
        ImageSearch, ix, iy, 0, 0, 2000, 300, Gear.jpg
        if (ErrorLevel = 2)
        {
            WinMinimize, A
        }
        else if errorlevel = 0
        {
            return hWnd
            WinMinimize, A
            ; MsgBox, Found it!
        }  
    }
```

and then if I want to create new I can send CTRL N to achieve.

**However, I want to check, is this really how it can be?**
Is there a running parameter of the exe file to give me the "Notes List" and "New Note" directly, since it's already availabe in the Jump List.

[Jump list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBzPP.png)

I really would love to hear some better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could also click on the Taskbar sticky icon by ImageSearch.
(Your use case kooks like a lot of ahk code for replacing 2 mouse clicks by 2 keystrokes.)

Comment: Hi, Thierry,
> "You could also click on the Taskbar sticky icon by ImageSearch" -- Yes i understand this part, and seem good idea.
> "use case kooks like a lot of ahk code for replacing 2 mouse clicks by 2 keystrokes." -- Sorry I got lost here. Could you please elaberate?

Answer (score 0):

ALternatively you can add a note in Outlook using the com object and it will be synced to Sticky Notes.

Comment: Thanks Thierry
But in fact i was using this approach.
it works but in the Outlook level, the font is wierd and not possible to adjust, since 2013.
I cannot read clealy if I type Asian texts. -- this doesn't happen to the UWP app.